# Why do i need both std and string library to use strings in c++

Tags: c++, string, std

I know that `string` type exists in `namespace std`. I also know there is the `<string>` library which needs to be included in order to use the `string` type. My question is: why do i need both (to include the library and use the std namespace) to define a string? Why cant i just use it by including the library? More generally, what does the `namespace std` contains that is missing from the library?

Comment: You don't need to use `using namespace std;`. You can qualify the namespace directly with the type. Just write `std::string s;`.

Comment: @Martin: `string` is not a template class, `basic_string` is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Namespaces and headers are two separate concepts doing entirely different things:

1. The header `<string>` declares the various entities related to the strings library like the class template `std::basic_string`, some `typedef`s like `std::string` and `std::wstring`, and some functions.
2. Namespaces are used to group related functionality and allow use of the same names in different namespaces. For example, a "vector" is essentially an array for some (this is the view taken by the standard C++ library defining this name in namespace `std`) while in other contexts it is a mathematical entity.

When you included `<string>` you got all entities related to the strings library declared inside namespace `std`. Some people object to the idea to use `std::string` because it is so much easier to use `string` instead. To aide this practice a *using directive*, i.e., a statement like `using namespace std;` can be used to look in namespace `std` for entities when looking up names. That is, the using directive merely makes names available without qualification.

Answer (score 2):

Look at it this way: `std::string` is the **complete name** of the type, much like "M. Kostas" is your complete name.

`#include <string>` gives you `std::string`. You can call it `string` only if you have first established the correct context, e.g. by `using namespace std` or by `using std::string`, or if you yourself happen to be library code within `namespace std { /* ... */ }`.

Again, consider the analogy with family names. I can only refer to you by "M." if I have first established that I am talking about the "Kostas" family (= `using namespace std`), or if I previously said that by "M." I actually mean "M. Kostas" (= `using std::string`) , or if I am myself a member of the "Kostas" family (= `namespace std { /* ... */ }`).

Note that you should (in the opinion of many programmers, at least, mine included) rarely use `using namespace std` or `using std::string`. It's often better to just use complete names everywhere. At global scope in header files, using shortcuts is even no longer a matter of style but can lead to real technical problems.